# print scala array of tuples with a map

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an Array of Tuple2 that contains a String and a map, and I'd like to print for each tuple2 as many rows as the number of keys of the map. This is what I wrote:

```
val a = Array(
           ("foo", HashMap(1->"f1", 2->"f2")),
           ("bar", HashMap(1->"b1", 2->"b2"))
        )

for (sourceNode <- a) {
   for (destNode <- sourceNode._2) {
     println("value [" + sourceNode._1 + "] for [" + destNode._1 + "] is '" + destNode._2 + "'")
   }
 }
```

and here is the result:

```
value [foo] for [1] is 'f1'
value [foo] for [2] is 'f2'
value [bar] for [1] is 'b1'
value [bar] for [2] is 'b2'
```

The result is correct, but is there a more concise (and functional) way to obtain this result?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: What you have is functional ... I am not sure you can get something "more functional" that that.

Comment: @marios what I meant with functional is using map() or flatMap() or something similar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP is looking for a solution using `map` and `flatMap` (instead of the syntactic sugar of for-comprehensions).

Here is one attempt to do that. First you decompose the (key,Map) pair into (key1,key2,value) tuple and then you just provide a print method. Here is the code:

```
val a = Array(
           ("foo", Map(1->"f1", 2->"f2")),
           ("bar", Map(1->"b1", 2->"b2"))
        )

a.flatMap{
   case(k,theMap) => theMap.map(e => (k,e._1,e._2))
}.foreach{ case(k1,k2,v) => println(s"value [$k1] for [$k2] is '$v'") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
for ((name, map) <- a) {
  for ((key, value) <- map) {
    println("value [" + name + "] for [" + key + "] is '" + value + "'")
  }
}
```

But you can make it even more concise

```
for {
  (name, map) <- a
  (key, value) <- map
} println(s"value [$name] for [$key] is '$value'")
```

Here is some more information on for comprehensions
http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your solution with `foreach`

```
a foreach { t => 
    t._2 foreach { m =>
      println("value [" + t._1 + "] for [" + m._1 + "] is '" + m._2 + "'")
    }
}
```